# Button to name and create parent node in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking to make a button called new. Using the click event there firstly should be a pop up (kinda like a messagebox? although it has to ask for a name).

After the user inputs the name and presses ok it should create a parent node of that name in the treeview. Also a cancel button should close the pop up.

Should i make another form or is there an easier way? Any advise/code would help a lot.

Comment: Do you know InputBox?

Comment: a parent node to the selected item or a parent node to the whole tree?

Answer (score 0):

I elected to go the other form route. I made the initial form (form1) which contains a tree view control and a button labeled "new".

Then I created a form for getting the user to input a name for a node. This form has a label, textbox, ok button, and cancel button.

This is the code for the NodeNameDialog form:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeViewExample
{
    public partial class NodeNameDialog : Form
    {
        public NodeNameDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NodeName = txtNodeName.Text ?? string.Empty;

            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        } 

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }

        public string NodeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in the original form, in the new button click event I call the node form as a dialog. The code for this is below.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeViewExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var nodeDialog = new NodeNameDialog();
            var result = nodeDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(nodeDialog.NodeName);
        }
    }
}
```

I originally include images but my rep is not high enough yet. Hope this helps!

*for simplicity I left out most validation

Comment: txtNodeName doesnt exist in current context?

Comment: the form I spoke of has a textbox named txtNodeName